# How to use If Else in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, select

I am selecting multiple columns from a table, eg. `type, orno, dsca`, etc.

I want to display 'dsca' value depending upon the value of 'type'. If 'type' = 9 or 10 then dsca = 'something' else dsca is from table

```
select 
    orno, dsca,type 
from 
    ttxdes102
where 
    type in (1, 4, 9, 10) 
    and IF (type = 9 or type = 10) then dsca = 'Unallocated' END

The actual table is:
|   orno   | type           | dsca             |
|   AV003  |  10            | null             |
|   HN001  |  1             | Sales Inv.       | 
|   HR007  |  9             | null             |
|   HQ001  |  2             | Advance Rcpt     |

I want to display it as:

|   orno   | type           | dsca             |
|   AV003  |  10            | Unallocated      |
|   HN001  |  1             | Sales Inv.       | 
|   HR007  |  9             | Unallocated      |
|   HQ001  |  2             | Advance Rcpt     |
```

Comment: `IF` is a logical flow operator, not a scalar function; it can't be used as part of a `SELECT` statement. Just use proper boolean logic with `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: Even if the above *was* valid, youd be missing a Boolean expression for the clause with the `IF`.

Comment: Seems you should use a CASE expression for "displaying" disca? But that's a guess because your question is not clear. It is always help to show an example of your source data and what your output / effect should be.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning different results depending on some condition is done with the [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) expression

```
select orno,
       case when type in (9, 10) then 'NOT Available' else dsca end as dsca,
       type 
from ttxdes102
where type in (1, 4, 9, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a `CASE` expression as

```
select orno, 
       case when [type] in (9, 10) then 'Unallocated' else dsca end dsca,
       [type] 
from 
    ttxdes102
```